# Create a nested list from a string

Tags: python, regex, list, nested-lists

Here is a string of zone locations and it's respective subzones in Singapore.

```
Bishan[1]
Bishan East
Marymount
Upper Thomson
Bukit Merah[2] (Not to be confused with Bukit Merah subzone.)
Alexandra Hill
Alexandra North
Bukit Ho Swee
Bukit Merah (Not to be confused with Bukit Merah planning area.)
City Terminals (Formerly called "Tanjong Pagar" subzone.)
Depot Road
Everton Park
Henderson Hill
Kampong Tiong Bahru
Maritime Square (Formerly called "HarbourFront" subzone.)
Redhill
Singapore General Hospital
Telok Blangah Drive
Telok Blangah Rise
Telok Blangah Way
Tiong Bahru
Tiong Bahru Station
Bukit Timah[3]
Anak Bukit
Coronation Road
Farrer Court
Hillcrest
Holland Road
Leedon Park
Swiss Club
Ulu Pandan
Downtown Core[4]
Anson
Bayfront
Bugis
Cecil
Central
City Hall
Clifford Pier
Marina Centre
Maxwell
Phillip
Raffles Place
Tanjong Pagar
Geylang[5]
Aljunied
Geylang East
Kallang Way
MacPherson
Kampong Ubi
Kallang[6]
Bendemeer
Boon Keng
Crawford
Geylang Bahru
Kallang Bahru
Kampong Bugis
Kampong Java
Lavender
Tanjong Rhu
```

or, as a Python string:

```
data = 'Bishan[1]\nBishan East\nMarymount\nUpper Thomson\nBukit Merah[2] (Not to be confused with Bukit Merah subzone.)\nAlexandra Hill\nAlexandra North\nBukit Ho Swee\nBukit Merah (Not to be confused with Bukit Merah planning area.)\nCity Terminals (Formerly called "Tanjong Pagar" subzone.)\nDepot Road\nEverton Park\nHenderson Hill\nKampong Tiong Bahru\nMaritime Square (Formerly called "HarbourFront" subzone.)\nRedhill\nSingapore General Hospital\nTelok Blangah Drive\nTelok Blangah Rise\nTelok Blangah Way\nTiong Bahru\nTiong Bahru Station\nBukit Timah[3]\nAnak Bukit\nCoronation Road\nFarrer Court\nHillcrest\nHolland Road\nLeedon Park\nSwiss Club\nUlu Pandan\nDowntown Core[4]\nAnson\nBayfront\nBugis\nCecil\nCentral\nCity Hall\nClifford Pier\nMarina Centre\nMaxwell\nPhillip\nRaffles Place\nTanjong Pagar\nGeylang[5]\nAljunied\nGeylang East\nKallang Way\nMacPherson\nKampong Ubi\nKallang[6]\nBendemeer\nBoon Keng\nCrawford\nGeylang Bahru\nKallang Bahru\nKampong Bugis\nKampong Java\nLavender\nTanjong Rhu\n'
```

The words with `square brackets[]` are the zones followed by the subzones separated by newlines `\n`. What I want to do is to created a list of zones with a sublist of the subzones like below (I will want to remove the square brackets and parentheses along with its contents later on):

**1.)** Bishan[1]

```
- Bishan East
- Marymount
- Upper Thomson
```

**2.)** Bukit Merah[2] (Not to be confused with Bukit Merah subzone.)

```
- Alexandra Hill
- Alexandra North
- Bukit Ho Swee
- Bukit Merah (Not to be confused with Bukit Merah planning area.)
- City Terminals (Formerly called "Tanjong Pagar" subzone.)
```

...

So far, I've only been able to extract the zones using split() and regex.

```
zones_and_subzones = data.split('\n')
zones = [zone for zone in zones_and_subzones if re.match(r'(.*?)\[', zone)]
```

This is where I'm stuck at, I have trouble trying to extract the subzones of each zone. I tried using

```
regex = (\].*?\[)
```

to extract the text between the closing and opening square brackets but its results are incomplete. I've been at this for a while and would appreciate the help. If there's a better approach than what I currently have, please do share. Thank you.

Comment: are you sure a nested array is what you are looking for and not a dictionary of lists?

Comment: Regex is not good for parsing nested stuff like HTML or XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it on linefeeds as you're doing, then go through it line by line and determine whether each line is a "title" or "content." Use a dictionary to access the content by title.

```
s = your data
result = {}
for item in s.splitlines():
    if '[' in item:
        key = item
        result[key] = []
    else:
        result[key].append(item)
```

The result is a dictionary like `{'Bishan[1]': ['Bishan East', 'Marymount', 'Upper Thomson'], ...}`.

Comment: I can't believe dictionaries didnt cross my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it is more advised to use a dictionary for that case, specifically i would use default dict for faster implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
dicti = defaultdict(lambda:[])
for word in str_data.split('\n'):
    if '[' in word and ']' in word:
        name = word
    else:
        dicti[name].append(word) # or alternatively -> `dicti[name] += [word]`
>>>dicti
{'Bishan[1]': ['Bishan East', 'Marymount', 'Upper Thomson'],
             'Bukit Merah[2] (Not to be confused with Bukit Merah subzone.)': ['Alexandra Hill',
              'Alexandra North',
              'Bukit Ho Swee',
              'Bukit Merah (Not to be confused with Bukit Merah planning area.)',
              'City Terminals (Formerly called "Tanjong Pagar" subzone.)',
              'Depot Road',
              'Everton Park',
              'Henderson Hill',
              'Kampong Tiong Bahru',
              'Maritime Square (Formerly called "HarbourFront" subzone.)',
              'Redhill',
              'Singapore General Hospital',
              'Telok Blangah Drive',
              'Telok Blangah Rise',
              'Telok Blangah Way',
              'Tiong Bahru',
              'Tiong Bahru Station'],
   #...
})
```

Comment: Why `dicti[name] += [word]` rather than `dicti[name].append(word)`?